# IE9 Questions page user reputation does not display correctly

Tags: support, markdown, internet-explorer

When looking at the StackOverflow questions on the question page in IE9, this is how the user reputation is displayed (This works fine in Firefox):

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. can't reproduce with IE10 running in "Browser Mode" of IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off Compatibility Mode (it should be grey, not blue), should be the thrid icon from the right (page with a "crack" in it). I hate when I accidently click it on. And I have to use IE at work... :(