# Comment vote vertical spacing is inconsistent on IE9

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface

I never thought I would be OCD about pixels but whenever I am involved in a Meta post with a lot of comments, I see this, and today I decided to draw some horizontal lines to prove I am not imagining it:

[image: comments and their votes]

The one that has the votes too far down is my own. (It's on [Deleted questions should not disappear from the Questions list in my Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181551/a-question-i-posted-that-was-closed-as-a-duplicate-disappeared) if you would like to try to repro, but I have seen this on every question where I've had an upvoted comment, I just never took a screenshot before.) I am guessing I can't upvote it or something and this makes the spacing different. Is it like that for everyone? Is it fixable?

Comment: Can you please link to the comment chain in question?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII done but it happens everywhere

Comment: Spacing looks perfect in my browser (I'm using the latest version of Chrome).

Comment: Same here (mobile safari 6.0). Must be an IE thing, then. If I wasn't such an apple fanboy I'd go digging in the CSS myself, but I don't want to get all dirty :)

Comment: if you want to repro, gang, be sure to look not at my upvoted comments but at one of your own, and you need one of someone else's to compare to.

Comment: Ah, well then it must have something to do with those invisible controls (or the lack thereof, in the case of your own comment) next to the number of votes.

Comment: I am going to go mental. (mentaller?) It is not doing it on this post. At least not while I can still edit. Will look at it again shortly.

Comment: @KateGregory Well, knowing this site, it's probably just been fixed already ;)

Comment: Not doing it on this post, still doing it on the one I linked to. So it's something more than just whether it's my comment or not.

Comment: Maybe similar to this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177775/ie9-questions-page-user-reputation-does-not-display-correctly/177781#177781

Comment: I'm not in Compat Mode.

Comment: looks perfectly fine in my Chrome & IE9

Comment: The critical factors here are that the comment must be yours (the logged-in viewer), and have a positive score, *and fit entirely on a single line (including signature and timestamp)*. See [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LiCKq.png) to get a feel for it.

Comment: Oh, and no repro on latest Firefox. Looks like an IE-only bug. ([Spin this.](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelb958/vSfXT/show/light/#ie))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the source of the problem - it's the delete button.

> [image]
>   <sub>screenshot taken on Firefox, in case you're wondering why it doesn't exhibit the bug</sub>

Specifically, the `margin-top: 3px` that applies to it. Internet Explorer does not react well to top margins of `3px` or more on that button.

> ## Firefox 24
>
> [image] [image]
>
> `0px` That delete button just looks misaligned to me.
>   `1px` Only slightly better.
>   `2px` The delete button appears perfectly lined up to me, and nothing else appears wrong.
>   `3px` *current value* Again, no real problems, except the delete button is out of alignment the other way.
>   `4px` Still boring.
>   `5px` Score *appears* to jump up a pixel, but it's just an optical illusion caused by the bottom border of the comment giving up and expanding.

> ## Internet Explorer 10
>
> [image] [image]
>
> `0px` More misaligned delete button.
>   `1px` Now looking slightly better...
>   `2px` The delete button's lined up right, but the score seems to have jumped up a pixel. (Possibly, however, it's just the optical illusion again.)
>   `3px` *current value* The score says "stuff this, I'm outta here" and begins to move in line with the delete button, which moves progressively further downwards as expected.

## Recommendation

```
.delete-tag { margin-top: 2px; }
```

And all your problems are solved.