# Comment score is misaligned for own single-line comments

Tags: bug, comments, design

When a comment by you, the logged-in user, fits on one line (the signature too) and has a nonzero score, the score indicator is slightly misaligned.

> [image]
>
> 1. Own single-line comment. **Misaligned.**
> 2. Other single-line comment (forced to two lines due to (invisible) vote and flag buttons). Correctly aligned.
> 3. Other single-line comment (not forced to two lines because I upvoted it). Correctly aligned.
> 4. Own multi-line comment. Correctly aligned.
> 5. (Not circled; just below 2.) Other multi-line comment. Correctly aligned.

Comment: My hero! You figured out what makes this happen! Here's my report from ages ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181560/comment-vote-vertical-spacing-is-inconsistent-on-ie9 But I didn't clue in that it was my own comments that were out of whack - which is why everyone else said "looks fine to me" Thankyou for making me feel slightly saner on an insane day :-)